# Каким должен быть хороший ответ на заданный вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение

Автор задал вопрос и рассчитывает получить  быстрое, точное и однозначное решение. А каким основным требованиям,  с ваше точки зрения,  должен отвечать хороший ответ?

**Мои предложения**

1) Ответ лучше сформулировать  и кратко изложить  **в самом начале текста** (а не в середине, конце и т.д.), а то его (при большом объёме)  можно не найти вовсе. (Кстати, это принцип инфостиля).

**2) О недостаточности информации говорилось много,** но это вовсе не призыв писать длинные сочинения. Ответ должен быть не объемным, а достаточным по содержанию.

3) **Об избыточности информации говорилось мало**. Например, надо ответить на конкретный вопрос, а вы на целую страницу излагаете **правила по всей теме, то есть всё, что  знаете сами.**  Всё это сложно читается, непонятно зачем дается, а автор вопроса рискует так и не добраться до сути дела.

4) **На правило лучше дать ссылку,** процитировав только самое главное.

5) **Выделите вашу авторскую часть**, ваше личное мнение (я думаю, что...), оно важно и интересно как оригинальная часть  ответа (особенно при решении нестандартной задачи), но при этом не является  общепринятым суждением.

6) При всём сказанном мне не хотелось бы,  чтобы ответы  напоминали стандартную схему, **хорошо, когда в них чувствуется авторский стиль**. Даже  короткие лирические отступления, данные к месту, иногда неплохо смотрятся и оживляют текст.

Comment: >> *хорошо, когда в них чувствуется авторский стиль.* Ну, это если "автор" настолько самонадеян, что думает, будто имеет свой "стиль".

Comment: Если вы скромны, застенчивы, не уверены в себе и не имеете авторского стиля, то можете пропустить этот пункт.

Comment: Sibylla! Используйте Мета-раздел сайта!

Answer (score 3):

1. По сути - предложение правильное.
   Но иногда вывод приходится делать на "основании вышеизложенного", в заключении рассуждений. **Главное**, чтобы ответ ***БЫЛ: понятный и верный.***

2., 3. Избыточность и недостаточность информации - мы все ***разные***: у кого-то "подвешен" язык, кто-то от природы скуп на слова.
Очень часто при "голом" ответе приходится нюансы или сомнения долго выяснять в комментариях.

4. Ссылка - вещь хорошая, полезная, при двух условиях:

   - информация должна быть *достоверная*.
     Пример: [**абзацы при прямой речи**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430813/%D0%90%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8)
   - информация должна быть *читабельная*.
     Иногда ссылка вообще пустая или не открывается, иногда - в ней не то, что "заявлено".
     Пример: [**"раскатать губу" - происхождение поговорки**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8)
     Желательно после оформления ответа это проверить.
5. *Я думаю (считаю, вижу...), что..; мне кажется; возможно, проблема в этом*  - да, ответ с таким собственным, иногда необычным мнением выглядит более "человечным", не по-менторски.
6. Сомнений не возникает: авторский стиль - это здОрово. Только тут нужны определенная смелость и, конечно, опыт ( мне, дилетанту, до этого далеко ).
7. Я бы добавила ещё один пункт: ***взаимное уважение*.**
   Не столь важно, **кто** задаёт вопрос - ученик или почтенная матрона, - важно не увидеть в ответ: *это и школьнику понятно; не надо мудрствовать! это я и без вас знаю; что тут думать?*
   Считаю, лучше вообще *не отвечать* на тот вопрос, который *не достоин* вашего высочайшего интеллектуального и профессионального уровня.

Answer (score 2):

Я согласен со всем, стараюсь даже придерживаться, но это в основном лишь благие пожелания.

Конкретно.
1) - тут да, однозначно да.
2)-6) - а тут все упирается в субъективность понимания.
Не буду показывать пальцем, но есть автор, который на вопрос "Вы не знаете, который час?" считает достаточным ответ "Знаю". А другой, увидев в правиле знакомое слово, готов применить его с криками "ты Розенталя уважаешь?", хотя Розенталь писал совсем о другом. Ну и со всем остальным - аналогично. Всё упирается в субъективность похода. Если нет единого, общеприемлемого мерила, то остаётся только каждому в отдельности указывать, что ответ недостаточен или, там, избыточен, а в правилах главное совсем не то, что этот товарищ углядел. А если критикуемый еще и воспринимает всё как личный наезд и начинает в чужих очах соринки разглядывать...  Туши свет.

(----)
*В порядке заявленного авторского "лирического отступления*.

На мой взгляд, первое, что можно и нужно бы сделать в этом направлении - выработать какой-то единый подход и понимание у администрации и "ядерных" участников цели самого существования ресурса. Пока об этом остается только мечтать.

Если это сервис типа "на **любые** вопросы даём **любые** ответы" и вообще "наш дом борется за звание дома выслкой культуры быта" , то это одно, качество ответов тут вообще побоку, давай количество, делай план, пеки пирожки с мясом. Всё что нужно - наживка для поисковиков, чтобы гоглояндексные ищейки давали ссылки на rus.stackexchange.com в первых результатах: броские и содержательные заголовки, использование ключевых слов в текстах, поменьше картинок и внешних ссылок.

А если есть претензии на какую-то профессиональность и качество ответов - это совсем другое... Тут нужна чисто научная требовательность - вплоть до  самоцензуры - и прочее.

Пока какого-то, даже самого элементарного, единства понимания я не вижу.